# Sumar elementos identicos arreglo multidimencional en php

Tags: php, array

Ojalá puedan ayudarme...

tengo este arreglo multidimencional...

```
$concepto =[
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9780521124362",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPLETE KEY FOR SCHOOLS WORKBOOK WITHOUT ANSWERS AND AUDIO CD",
        "cantidad"=>"143.00",
        "importe"=>"3469.18",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107417823",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPACT ADVANCED WORKBOOK WITHOUT ANSWERS AND DOWNLOADABLE AUDIO FILE",
        "cantidad"=>"24.00",
        "importe"=>"402.24",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107428553",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPACT FIRST 2ED WORKBOOK WITHOUT ANSWERS AND AUDIO CD",
        "cantidad"=>"24.00",
        "importe"=>"410.16",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107613836",
        "descripcion"=>"CAMBRIDGE GLOBAL ENGLISH ACTIVITY BOOK 3",
        "cantidad"=>"23.00",
        "importe"=>"251.62",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107613836",
        "descripcion"=>"CAMBRIDGE GLOBAL ENGLISH ACTIVITY BOOK 3",
        "cantidad"=>"26.00",
        "importe"=>"284.44",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107618800",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPACT KEY FOR SCHOOLS WORKBOOK WITHOUT ANSWERS AND AUDIO CD",
        "cantidad"=>"48.00",
        "importe"=>"820.32",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107619814",
        "descripcion"=>"CAMBRIDGE GLOBAL ENGLISH LEARNER'S BOOK WITH AUDIO CD 5",
        "cantidad"=>"4.00",
        "importe"=>"87.52",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107621237",
        "descripcion"=>"CAMBRIDGE GLOBAL ENGLISH ACTIVITY BOOK 5",
        "cantidad"=>"47.00",
        "importe"=>"514.18",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107626867",
        "descripcion"=>"CAMBRIDGE GLOBAL ENGLISH ACTIVITY BOOK 6",
        "cantidad"=>"7.00",
        "importe"=>"76.58",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107635395",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPACT PRELIMINARY FOR SCHOOLS WORKBOOK WITHOUT ANSWERS AND AUDIO CD",
        "cantidad"=>"192.00",
        "importe"=>"3281.28",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
    ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781107671799",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPLETE FIRST FOR SCHOOLS WORKBOOK WITHOUT ANSWERS AND AUDIO CD",
        "cantidad"=>"96.00",
        "importe"=>"2328.96",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
     ],
    [
        "noIdentificacionC"=>"9781108349093",
        "descripcion"=>"COMPACT PRELIMINARY FOR SCHOOLS 2ED STUDENT'S PACK",
        "cantidad"=>"72.00",
        "importe"=>"3024.00",
        "unidad"=>"PIEZA"
     ]
    ];
```

El cual se repite el `noIdentificacion`, no se me ocurre como los que esten repetidos sumarlos para que solo haya un `noIdentificacion` y no se repita,
ya intente recorrerlo con un `foreach` y utilizar `in_array` para guardarlo dentro de otro arreglo, pero no me funciono o quizas no lo hice correctamente... ojala puedan orientarme un poco, no se de que forma guardar el `noIdentificador` y luego  comparando con el `array` principal para ir acumulando los valores de esos identificadores que se repiten para hacer un nuevo `array` sin repeticiones...

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ir iterando los elementos e ir guardándolos en un array secundario usando como key el `noIdentificacionC`. Si en el momento de guardar un elemento, ya existía esa key, lo sumas en vez de agregarlo. Me explico mejor con el código:

```php
$concepto_por_noIdentificacionC = [];
foreach( $concepto as  $concepto_i) {
    $noIdentificacionC_i = $concepto_i['noIdentificacionC'];

    if(empty($concepto_por_noIdentificacionC[$noIdentificacionC_i])) {
        $concepto_por_noIdentificacionC[$noIdentificacionC_i] = $concepto_i;
    }else {
        $concepto_por_noIdentificacionC[$noIdentificacionC_i]['cantidad'] += $concepto_i['cantidad'];
    }
}

$concepto_sin_duplicados = array_values($concepto_por_noIdentificacionC);
```